# Stemming parameter in Solr

Tags: solr, stemming

Is there any parameter like (edismax or dismax or any other) that i can set for stemming to work in Solr or i need to make changes in schema.xml of Solr to implement the stemming ?
Problem is if i change schema.xml by default stemming/phoentic work which i dont want ? I am using Solr from third party application and in UI we have checkbox for stemming to check/uncheck , i pass these paramaters to Solr and get the data from Solr, i cant pass this UI parameter to SOlr, so if there is any parameter at Solr side i can pass that for stemming to work ?

Please let me know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stemming is performed as part of the analysis chain, and therefor is part of how the schema for that particular field is defined.

The reason for this becomes apparent when you consider how stemming works - for stemming to make sense, the term has to be stemmed *when it's being indexed*, as well as when being queried.

Lucene takes your input string, runs it through your analysis chain and saves the generated tokens to its index. Giving it `what are you asking` will probably end up as `what`, `are`, `you`, `ask` after tokenizing by whitespace and applying stemming.

The same operation happens when querying, so if someone searches for `asks`, the token gets stemmed to `ask` - and then compared against what's in the index. If stemming hadn't taken place when indexing, you'd end up with `asking` in the index, and `ask` when querying - and that isn't a match, since the tokens aren't the same.

In your third party application the stemming option probably performs stemming inside the application before sending the content to Solr.

You can also [use the Schema API to dynamically update and change field type definitions](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/schema-api.html).

Comment: Ok so that means there is no parameter as such it has to be done at schema level and schema.xml need to be changed for same, right ?

Comment: That's correct, but that doesn't mean it has to be changed for everything you index. Add (or update) a specific field type with your stemming configuration, then use `copyField` or similar to index the same content into multiple fields, and search each field accordingly depending on your need (you can use `qf` in (e)dismax to search in multiple fields at the same time). That way you can dynamically decide how you want to search (and how to weigh the different fields), and get the behaviour you want.

Comment: At Solr side, schema.xml i have done changes for stemming and phonetic, i have introduced three fields( 1 for stemming, 1 for phoentic, 1 for normal text) in my schema. by default field with normal text will be searched, when client selects stemming or phonetic from client UI respective fields will be searched in solr. Is there any better way of doing this as i am duplicating the content in ( stemming field and phoentic field) ??

Comment: That sounds like the correct way of doing that. You don't have to have the fields set to stored, so set `stored="false"`. That way you avoid storing the actual content multiple times, just the specific tokens for each field.